# I'm running into an error with the following snipet here

Tags: php, forms

I'm running into an error with the following snipet here

```
<?php
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Your input value is invalid");';
    echo '</srcipt>';
?>
```

Comment: In case the previous comment was not enough: You have spelling error the word **script** within the `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it was given in the comment I guess the OP still can't able to get it, to make end,

**Here's the answer**

You have typo in the `srcipt` instead of `script`

Just change it inside your code, then everything will work fine

```
<?php
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Your input value is invalid");';
    echo '</script>';
?>
```

And i recommend you to do it in a single line instead of having three echo

```
<?php
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Your input value is invalid");</script>';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Sulthan Allaudeen. In programming these small mistakes are mind blowing.

Comment: Ok, @Sulthan Allaudeen